# Recyclerview controls duplication

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I really could use some help here. got several DAYS trying to figure out whats wrong and cant find it. Here is the thing

every time I do data.remove(position) notifyitemremove(position) it desyncs and deletes items to right but the items deletes well untill the list arrives to the first item and then app crashes.

Then I use notifyitemrangechange(position,data.size()) and id keeps the position track good BUT something happen to the views and they start getting trash data from deleted views... the issue is driving me crazy, ill attach images and the adapter since everythin happens there.

It is important to notice that if I delete views from the right to the left, everything works just perfect. the recycler scrolls horizontally.

[fresh start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ujT9.jpg)
[after deletion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkAcI.jpg)

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder{

        private ArrayList<Comanda> list_comandas;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;


            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.list_comandas = list_comandas;
         }

        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount()
        {
            return list_comandas.size();
        }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Comanda comanda = list_comandas.get(position);

            holder.setData(comanda, position);

      //  mostrarMensaje("agregado:" + position);



    private void mostrarMensaje(String mensaje)
    {
        Toast.makeText(inflater.getContext(), mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }



    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  implements View.OnClickListener{

        //definicioin de variables

        TextView txt_comanda;
        TextView txt_mesa;
        TextView tid;
        TextView torden;
        TextView te;

        Button btn_cerrar;
        Button be;
        LinearLayout le;
        private LinearLayout lyocomanda;

        private int position;
        private int anchomanda = Math.round(inflater.getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.parents_size));

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            //inicializacion de controles

            lyocomanda = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lyocomanda);

            txt_comanda = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_comanda);

            txt_mesa = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_mesa);

            tid = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tid);

            torden = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.torden);

            btn_cerrar = (Button) itemView.findViewWithTag("primal");
            btn_cerrar.setOnClickListener(MyViewHolder.this);

        }

        void setData(Comanda comanda, int position) {

            //setear la data

            this.position = position;

            String cadena= comanda.getOrden();

            Integer tope = cadena.length();

            Boolean tijera_categoria = false;
            Boolean tijera_articulo = true;
            Boolean tijera_contorno = true;
            Boolean tijera_cambio = true;
            boolean creador=false;

            Integer indisup;
            Integer indiin = 0;
            char apuntador;
            String Buscado = "";
            String Buscado_contorno = "";
            String Buscado_categoria = "";
            Integer id = -1;

            String tag="";

            this.txt_comanda.setText(this.position+"");

            this.txt_mesa.setText(comanda.getMesa());

            this.tid.setText(comanda.get_id());

            this.torden.setText(comanda.getOrden());

            this.btn_cerrar.setOnClickListener(MyViewHolder.this);


            for (int i = 0; i < tope ; i++) {


                apuntador =cadena.charAt(i);

                if (Buscado.equals("Bebidas"))
                {
                    cadena="";
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (apuntador == '$')
                    {
                        cadena="";
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //EJECUCION PRINCIPAL

                        if (apuntador == '#' && !tijera_categoria) {
                            if (i == 0) {
                                indiin = i + 1;
                            }
                        }

                        if (apuntador == '!' && !tijera_categoria) {
                            tijera_categoria = true;
                            tijera_articulo = false;
                            indisup = i;

                            id =id+1;

                            Buscado = cadena.substring(indiin, indisup);
                            indiin = indisup + 1;

                            Buscado_categoria = Buscado;

                            tag= position + ""+id;
                            this.be = new Button(inflater.getContext());
                            creador= true;
                            this.be.setTag(tag);
                           // this.be.setId(position);
                            this.be.setOnClickListener(MyViewHolder.this);
                        }

                        if (apuntador == '%' && !tijera_articulo) {
                            indisup = i;
                            tijera_articulo = true;
                            tijera_contorno = false;

                            Buscado = cadena.substring(indiin, indisup);

                            indiin = indisup + 1;

                            this.be.setTextSize((inflater.getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.txt_size)) / 2);
                            if (Buscado_categoria.equals("Fondos")) {
                                this.be.setBackgroundTintList(inflater.getContext().getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.fondos, null));
                            }
                            if (Buscado_categoria.equals("Entradas")) {
                                this.be.setBackgroundTintList(inflater.getContext().getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.entradas, null));
                            }
                            if (Buscado_categoria.equals("Postres")) {
                                this.be.setBackgroundTintList(inflater.getContext().getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.postres, null));
                            }
                            be.setText(Buscado);
                            be.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(this.anchomanda, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                            this.lyocomanda.addView(be);
                        }

                        if (apuntador == '*' && !tijera_contorno) {
                            indisup = i;
                            tijera_cambio = false;

                            Buscado = cadena.substring(indiin, indisup);
                            indiin = indisup + 1;

                            if (!Buscado.equals("")) {
                                Buscado_contorno = Buscado;
                                this.te = new TextView(inflater.getContext());
                                this.te.setText(Buscado);
                                this.te.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                                this.te.setTextSize((inflater.getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.txt_size)) / 2);

                                if (creador){
                                    this.le = new LinearLayout((inflater.getContext()));
                                    creador=false;
                                }


                                this.le.addView(this.te);

                            }

                        }

                        if (apuntador == '#' && !tijera_cambio) {
                            indisup = i;
                            tijera_contorno = true;
                            tijera_cambio = true;
                            tijera_categoria = false;

                            Buscado = cadena.substring(indiin, indisup);
                            indiin = indisup + 1;

                            if (!Buscado_contorno.equals("")) {
                                this.le.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(anchomanda, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                                this.le.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                                this.le.setBackground(inflater.getContext().getDrawable(customborder));
                                this.lyocomanda.addView(this.le);
                                //cadena ="";
                            }

                        }


                    }//FIN DE LA EJECUCION PRINCIPAL
                }//DEL INICIO DE EJECUCION PRINCIPAL

            }// DEL FOR

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            if (v.getTag().equals("primal")){
                mostrarMensaje("borrado" + position);
                removeItem(position);
            }else{
                mostrarMensaje("BOTON NO CONFIGURADO:" + v.getTag().toString());
            }
        }

        private void removeItem(int position) {
            list_comandas.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
            //notifyItemRangeChanged(position,list_comandas.size());
            //notifyItemRangeChanged(position, getItemCount() - position);
           // notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        private void addItem(int position, Comanda comanda) {
            list_comandas.add(position, comanda);
            notifyItemInserted(position);
            notifyItemRangeChanged(position,list_comandas.size());
            //notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
    }
```

the basic adapter recycler row is :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<!--   Recycler View Item Row   -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/comanda"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:background="@drawable/customborder">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/lyocabeza"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/parents_size"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lbl_comanda"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size"
                android:text="Comanda:"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_comanda"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lbl_comanda"
                android:hint="00000"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_mesa"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size"
                android:hint="9999"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lbl_mesa"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size"
                android:text="Mesa:"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txt_mesa"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_cerrar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/lbl_comanda"
                android:text="Cerrar Comanda"
                android:tag="primal"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tid"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/torden"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>


        </RelativeLayout>


        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/lyocabeza">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lyocomanda"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <!--   AUTO GENERATED CONTROLS   -->



            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>



    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

as you can see my data is dynamic and i need more or less controls depending on data so the row CANT be static, well thats it for now, thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your approach is the use of `position` inside `MyViewHolder`. You should note this on `onBindViewHolder`:

> RecyclerView will not call this method
>            again if the position of the item changes in the data set unless the item itself is
>            invalidated or the new position cannot be determined. For this reason, you should only
>            use the `position` parameter while acquiring the related data item inside
>            this method and should not keep a copy of it. If you need the position of an item later
>            on (e.g. in a click listener), use {@link ViewHolder#getAdapterPosition()} which will have the updated adapter position.

So after you remove an item the position of others are affected and may ended using an incorrect position when they trigger the remove event, remember that the views are recycled.

You should refer to the current item's position with `holder.getAdapterPosition()`.

Try something like this:

handling the `onCLickListener` outside the ViewHolder

**MyViewHolder**

```
class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        //definicioin de variables

        TextView txt_comanda;
        TextView txt_mesa;
        TextView tid;
        TextView torden;
        TextView te;

        Button btn_cerrar;
        Button be;
        LinearLayout le;
        private LinearLayout lyocomanda;

        private int anchomanda = Math.round(inflater.getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.parents_size));

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            //inicializacion de controles

            lyocomanda = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lyocomanda);

            txt_comanda = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_comanda);

            txt_mesa = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_mesa);

            tid = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tid);

            torden = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.torden);

            btn_cerrar = (Button) itemView.findViewWithTag("primal");

        }

        void setData(Comanda comanda) {

            //setear la data

            String cadena= comanda.getOrden();

            Integer tope = cadena.length();

            Boolean tijera_categoria = false;
            Boolean tijera_articulo = true;
            Boolean tijera_contorno = true;
            Boolean tijera_cambio = true;
            boolean creador=false;

            Integer indisup;
            Integer indiin = 0;
            char apuntador;
            String Buscado = "";
            String Buscado_contorno = "";
            String Buscado_categoria = "";
            Integer id = -1;

            String tag="";

            this.txt_comanda.setText(this.position+"");

            this.txt_mesa.setText(comanda.getMesa());

            this.tid.setText(comanda.get_id());

            this.torden.setText(comanda.getOrden());

            for (int i = 0; i < tope ; i++) {


                apuntador =cadena.charAt(i);

                if (Buscado.equals("Bebidas"))
                {
                    cadena="";
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (apuntador == '$')
                    {
                        cadena="";
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //EJECUCION PRINCIPAL

                        if (apuntador == '#' && !tijera_categoria) {
                            if (i == 0) {
                                indiin = i + 1;
                            }
                        }

                        if (apuntador == '!' && !tijera_categoria) {
                            tijera_categoria = true;
                            tijera_articulo = false;
                            indisup = i;

                            id =id+1;

                            Buscado = cadena.substring(indiin, indisup);
                            indiin = indisup + 1;

                            Buscado_categoria = Buscado;

                            tag= position + ""+id;
                            this.be = new Button(inflater.getContext());
                            creador= true;
                            this.be.setTag(tag);
                           // this.be.setId(position);
                            this.be.setOnClickListener(MyViewHolder.this);
                        }

                        if (apuntador == '%' && !tijera_articulo) {
                            indisup = i;
                            tijera_articulo = true;
                            tijera_contorno = false;

                            Buscado = cadena.substring(indiin, indisup);

                            indiin = indisup + 1;

                            this.be.setTextSize((inflater.getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.txt_size)) / 2);
                            if (Buscado_categoria.equals("Fondos")) {
                                this.be.setBackgroundTintList(inflater.getContext().getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.fondos, null));
                            }
                            if (Buscado_categoria.equals("Entradas")) {
                                this.be.setBackgroundTintList(inflater.getContext().getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.entradas, null));
                            }
                            if (Buscado_categoria.equals("Postres")) {
                                this.be.setBackgroundTintList(inflater.getContext().getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.postres, null));
                            }
                            be.setText(Buscado);
                            be.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(this.anchomanda, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                            this.lyocomanda.addView(be);
                        }

                        if (apuntador == '*' && !tijera_contorno) {
                            indisup = i;
                            tijera_cambio = false;

                            Buscado = cadena.substring(indiin, indisup);
                            indiin = indisup + 1;

                            if (!Buscado.equals("")) {
                                Buscado_contorno = Buscado;
                                this.te = new TextView(inflater.getContext());
                                this.te.setText(Buscado);
                                this.te.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                                this.te.setTextSize((inflater.getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.txt_size)) / 2);

                                if (creador){
                                    this.le = new LinearLayout((inflater.getContext()));
                                    creador=false;
                                }


                                this.le.addView(this.te);

                            }

                        }

                        if (apuntador == '#' && !tijera_cambio) {
                            indisup = i;
                            tijera_contorno = true;
                            tijera_cambio = true;
                            tijera_categoria = false;

                            Buscado = cadena.substring(indiin, indisup);
                            indiin = indisup + 1;

                            if (!Buscado_contorno.equals("")) {
                                this.le.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(anchomanda, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                                this.le.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                                this.le.setBackground(inflater.getContext().getDrawable(customborder));
                                this.lyocomanda.addView(this.le);
                                //cadena ="";
                            }

                        }


                    }//FIN DE LA EJECUCION PRINCIPAL
                }//DEL INICIO DE EJECUCION PRINCIPAL

            }// DEL FOR

        }
```

**MyAdapter**

```
...

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Comanda comanda = list_comandas.get(position);

    holder.setData(comanda);

    // set onCLickListener 
    holder.btn_cerrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            removeItem(holder.getAdapterPosition());
        }
    });

   //  mostrarMensaje("agregado:" + position);

}

...
```

Or you can also handle the `onCLickListener` inside the ViewHolder

**MyViewHolder**

```
class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  implements View.OnClickListener{

        //definicioin de variables

        TextView txt_comanda;
        TextView txt_mesa;
        TextView tid;
        TextView torden;
        TextView te;

        Button btn_cerrar;
        Button be;
        LinearLayout le;
        private LinearLayout lyocomanda;

        private int anchomanda = Math.round(inflater.getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.parents_size));

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            //inicializacion de controles

            lyocomanda = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lyocomanda);

            txt_comanda = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_comanda);

            txt_mesa = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_mesa);

            tid = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tid);

            torden = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.torden);

            btn_cerrar = (Button) itemView.findViewWithTag("primal");
            btn_cerrar.setOnClickListener(MyViewHolder.this);

        }

        void setData(Comanda comanda) {

            //setear la data

            String cadena= comanda.getOrden();

            Integer tope = cadena.length();

            Boolean tijera_categoria = false;
            Boolean tijera_articulo = true;
            Boolean tijera_contorno = true;
            Boolean tijera_cambio = true;
            boolean creador=false;

            Integer indisup;
            Integer indiin = 0;
            char apuntador;
            String Buscado = "";
            String Buscado_contorno = "";
            String Buscado_categoria = "";
            Integer id = -1;

            String tag="";

            this.txt_comanda.setText(this.position+"");

            this.txt_mesa.setText(comanda.getMesa());

            this.tid.setText(comanda.get_id());

            this.torden.setText(comanda.getOrden());

            for (int i = 0; i < tope ; i++) {


                apuntador =cadena.charAt(i);

                if (Buscado.equals("Bebidas"))
                {
                    cadena="";
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (apuntador == '$')
                    {
                        cadena="";
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //EJECUCION PRINCIPAL

                        if (apuntador == '#' && !tijera_categoria) {
                            if (i == 0) {
                                indiin = i + 1;
                            }
                        }

                        if (apuntador == '!' && !tijera_categoria) {
                            tijera_categoria = true;
                            tijera_articulo = false;
                            indisup = i;

                            id =id+1;

                            Buscado = cadena.substring(indiin, indisup);
                            indiin = indisup + 1;

                            Buscado_categoria = Buscado;

                            tag= position + ""+id;
                            this.be = new Button(inflater.getContext());
                            creador= true;
                            this.be.setTag(tag);
                           // this.be.setId(position);
                            this.be.setOnClickListener(MyViewHolder.this);
                        }

                        if (apuntador == '%' && !tijera_articulo) {
                            indisup = i;
                            tijera_articulo = true;
                            tijera_contorno = false;

                            Buscado = cadena.substring(indiin, indisup);

                            indiin = indisup + 1;

                            this.be.setTextSize((inflater.getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.txt_size)) / 2);
                            if (Buscado_categoria.equals("Fondos")) {
                                this.be.setBackgroundTintList(inflater.getContext().getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.fondos, null));
                            }
                            if (Buscado_categoria.equals("Entradas")) {
                                this.be.setBackgroundTintList(inflater.getContext().getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.entradas, null));
                            }
                            if (Buscado_categoria.equals("Postres")) {
                                this.be.setBackgroundTintList(inflater.getContext().getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.postres, null));
                            }
                            be.setText(Buscado);
                            be.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(this.anchomanda, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                            this.lyocomanda.addView(be);
                        }

                        if (apuntador == '*' && !tijera_contorno) {
                            indisup = i;
                            tijera_cambio = false;

                            Buscado = cadena.substring(indiin, indisup);
                            indiin = indisup + 1;

                            if (!Buscado.equals("")) {
                                Buscado_contorno = Buscado;
                                this.te = new TextView(inflater.getContext());
                                this.te.setText(Buscado);
                                this.te.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                                this.te.setTextSize((inflater.getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.txt_size)) / 2);

                                if (creador){
                                    this.le = new LinearLayout((inflater.getContext()));
                                    creador=false;
                                }


                                this.le.addView(this.te);

                            }

                        }

                        if (apuntador == '#' && !tijera_cambio) {
                            indisup = i;
                            tijera_contorno = true;
                            tijera_cambio = true;
                            tijera_categoria = false;

                            Buscado = cadena.substring(indiin, indisup);
                            indiin = indisup + 1;

                            if (!Buscado_contorno.equals("")) {
                                this.le.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(anchomanda, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                                this.le.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                                this.le.setBackground(inflater.getContext().getDrawable(customborder));
                                this.lyocomanda.addView(this.le);
                                //cadena ="";
                            }

                        }


                    }//FIN DE LA EJECUCION PRINCIPAL
                }//DEL INICIO DE EJECUCION PRINCIPAL

            }// DEL FOR

        }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        if (v.getTag().equals("primal")){
            mostrarMensaje("borrado" + position);
            removeItem(position);
        }else{
            mostrarMensaje("BOTON NO CONFIGURADO:" + v.getTag().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it is nothing wrong in handling `onCLickListener` indside the view holder, in fact view holder should be used for that since in your solution you are creating a new `View.OnClickListener` each time `onBindViewHolder` gets called, all you need is to use `ViewHolder#get*Position` method

Comment: @pskink, you are right, I edited my answer to point out just the fact of use `ViewHolder#getAdapterPositon()` in any case.

Comment: exactly, this is it: `class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  implements View.OnClickListener`